# How can i get the child input(checkbox) html element?

Tags: javascript, dom

This is my current code

```
const unitDiv = document.querySelector(
              `[data-schemapath="${options.form_name_root}.outcomes.improvements.${outcomeIndex}.outcomes.${individualOutComeIndex}.parameters.items.${eachItemIndex}.unit"]`
            );

const unitDivCheckbox = unitDiv?.firstChild?.firstChild?.firstChild;

if (unitDivCheckbox) {
        (unitDivCheckbox as HTMLElement).style.display = 'none';
 }
```

As you can see I am using multiple `firstChild`. I want to avoid that.

What I want to remove is an `input checkbox`. Is there any smart way to make this works?

Side Note.

There is only 1 `input checkbox` inside `unitDiv`.

HTML

```
<div class="je-panel je-object__container" id="Edit Poll.outcomes.improvements.0.outcomes.0.parameters.items.0" data-schematype="object" data-schemapath="Edit Poll.outcomes.improvements.0.outcomes.0.parameters.items.0" style=""><h4 style="display: inline-block;" class="je-object__title"><button type="button" title="Collapse" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2 my-1 json-editor-btn-collapse json-editor-btntype-toggle"><i class="icon icon-arrow-down"></i><span> </span></button><label>item 1</label></h4><span class="btn-group je-object__controls" style="display: none;"><div style="display: none;" class="je-modal"><textarea class="form-input je-edit-json--textarea"></textarea><button type="button" title="Save" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2 my-1 json-editor-btn-save json-editor-btntype-save"><i class="icon icon-check"></i><span> Save</span></button><button type="button" title="Copy" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2 my-1 json-editor-btn-copy json-editor-btntype-copy"><i class="icon icon-copy"></i><span> Copy</span></button><button type="button" title="Cancel" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2 my-1 json-editor-btn-cancel json-editor-btntype-cancel"><i class="icon icon-cross"></i><span> Cancel</span></button></div><div style="display: none;" class="je-modal"><div class="property-selector"></div><input type="text" class="form-input property-selector-input" placeholder="Property name..."><button type="button" title="Add" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2 my-1 json-editor-btn-add json-editor-btntype-add"><i class="icon icon-plus"></i><span> Add</span></button><div style="clear: both;"></div></div><button type="button" title="Edit JSON" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2 my-1 json-editor-btn-edit json-editor-btntype-editjson"><i class="icon icon-edit"></i><span> JSON</span></button><button type="button" title="Object Properties" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2 my-1 json-editor-btn-edit_properties json-editor-btntype-properties" style="display: none;"><i class="icon icon-menu"></i><span> properties</span></button></span><div style="display: none;"></div><div class="je-panel"><div class="container je-noindent"><div><div class="columns"><div class="column col-12" data-schematype="string" data-schemapath="Edit Poll.outcomes.improvements.0.outcomes.0.parameters.items.0.category"><div class="form-group"><label class="required je-label form-label">category</label><input type="text" class="form-input" disabled="" readonly="true" name="Edit Poll[outcomes][improvements][0][outcomes][0][parameters][items][0][category]" aria-label="Edit Poll[outcomes][improvements][0][outcomes][0][parameters][items][0][category]"></div><div></div></div></div><div class="columns"><div class="column col-12" data-schematype="string" data-schemapath="Edit Poll.outcomes.improvements.0.outcomes.0.parameters.items.0.name"><div class="form-group"><label class="required je-label form-label">name</label><input type="text" class="form-input" disabled="" readonly="true" name="Edit Poll[outcomes][improvements][0][outcomes][0][parameters][items][0][name]" aria-label="Edit Poll[outcomes][improvements][0][outcomes][0][parameters][items][0][name]"></div><div></div></div></div><div class="columns"><div class="column col-12" data-schematype="string" data-schemapath="Edit Poll.outcomes.improvements.0.outcomes.0.parameters.items.0.screen"><div class="form-group"><label class="required je-label form-label">screen</label><input type="text" class="form-input" disabled="" readonly="true" name="Edit Poll[outcomes][improvements][0][outcomes][0][parameters][items][0][screen]" aria-label="Edit Poll[outcomes][improvements][0][outcomes][0][parameters][items][0][screen]"></div><div></div></div></div><div class="columns"><div class="column col-12" data-schematype="string" data-schemapath="Edit Poll.outcomes.improvements.0.outcomes.0.parameters.items.0.unit"><div class="form-group"><label class="je-label form-label"><input type="checkbox" style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px; display: none;" class="json-editor-opt-in">unit</label><input type="text" class="form-input" disabled="" readonly="true" name="Edit Poll[outcomes][improvements][0][outcomes][0][parameters][items][0][unit]" aria-label="Edit Poll[outcomes][improvements][0][outcomes][0][parameters][items][0][unit]"></div><div></div></div></div><div class="columns"><div class="column col-12" data-schematype="string" data-schemapath="Edit Poll.outcomes.improvements.0.outcomes.0.parameters.items.0.strength"><div class="form-group"><label class="je-label form-label"><input type="checkbox" style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px; display: none;" class="json-editor-opt-in">strength</label><input type="text" class="form-input" disabled="" readonly="true" name="Edit Poll[outcomes][improvements][0][outcomes][0][parameters][items][0][strength]" aria-label="Edit Poll[outcomes][improvements][0][outcomes][0][parameters][items][0][strength]"></div><div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div></div><span class="btn-group"><button type="button" title="Delete item" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2 my-1 json-editor-btn-delete delete json-editor-btntype-delete" data-i="0"><i class="icon icon-delete"></i><span> item</span></button><button type="button" title="Move down" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2 my-1 json-editor-btn-movedown movedown json-editor-btntype-move" data-i="0" style="display: none;"><i class="icon icon-downward"></i><span> </span></button></span></div>
```

Comment: Post HTML and JavaScript as a [mcve].

Comment: _"Is there any smart way to make this works?"_ - sure, use the power of CSS selection, that's what `querySelector` is _for_ ... `[data-schemapath="..."] input[type=checkbox]`

Comment: @zer00ne I don't post HTML at first because i think its not needed since i mention that there is only 1 `input checkbox` inside the whole div.

@CBroe  Thanks your solution works

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet doesn't reveal enough about the DOM structure. However,
if this Code block is executed as a response to an event that has happened over that checkbox then you should be able to access the DOM element (`target`) directly from the event object. Another approach would be if you have control over the DOM structure then you can add a specific `class` or `id` to the DOM element that you want to query. Last is to use a query similar to this

```
[data-schemapath="${options.form_name_root}.outcomes.improvements.${outcomeIndex}.outcomes.${individualOutComeIndex}.parameters.items.${eachItemIndex}.unit"] > [type=checkbox]
```

I would strongly suggest that you detail your example further to get answers that are more specific to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I don't have control over adding `id` or `class` over specific node in this case.
These dom are manipulated over 3rd party library. So adding or removing certain node is not under my control

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` use css selectors

```
const unitDivCheckbox = document.querySelector(
    `[data-schemapath="${options.form_name_root}.outcomes.improvements.${outcomeIndex}.outcomes.${individualOutComeIndex}.parameters.items.${eachItemIndex}.unit"] input[type=checkbox]`
);

if (unitDivCheckbox) {
    (unitDivCheckbox as HTMLElement).style.display = 'none';
}
```

or you can use `querySelector` again

```
...
const unitDivCheckbox = unitDiv?.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]')

if (unitDivCheckbox) {
    (unitDivCheckbox as HTMLElement).style.display = 'none';
}
```